# docker-compose.vs.release.yml Volume binding on VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

This is a docker file for .net core web application project. 
I am trying to understand what these lines means.

- What does ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro means.
- When I create files they are stored in root of my project folder as well. arent they suppose to be stored in container volumes.
- How do I map volumes properly and delete the contents of these volumes.

  ```
   version: '2'

  services:

   is.mvcclient:
  build:
    args:
      source: ${DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE}
  volumes:
    - ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
  entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
  labels:
    - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetope ratingsystem=linux"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro basically means that local folder ~/clrdbg will be available in the container under /clrdbg and local changes will be also reflected in the container without the need to rebuild the image. RO means that it is read-only so the container can't change the files in that folder.
- Your volume is mounted to a host folder (in this case I assume your projects root). Like mentioned in the previous point, in that case changes in local filesystem are reflected in the container.
- First you have to get your project into the container, so I guess you can COPY/ADD it to the container on image build. After that you have to do something along the lines of:

  ```
  services:
      is.mvcclient:
          volumes:
          - data-volume:/clrdbg
  volumes:
    data-volume:
  ```

  By doing that, all the changes to the files in the container will only be reflected in those files, not the local ones. Of course, that goes both ways - changes to local files won't be reflected in the container files.